# i deployed singe page app to firebase but no render

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

i deployed single page app to firebase but no render appear. I was wondering the problem is in Router. I think it can't Redirect from "/" to "/public", but it had redirected but no render appear. When i `npm start` locally, it's working normally. Please Help..

```
const App = props => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" component={Login} />
        <Route
          exact
          path="/register"
          name="Register Page"
          component={Register}
        />
        <Route path="/public" name="Public" component={Public} />
        <Route path="/admin" name="Admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route path="/gudang" name="Gudang" component={DefaultLayout} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/public" />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try it . But it could be a possible solution.

instead of

```
        <Redirect from="/" to="/public" />>
```

Write

```
<Route 
  path="/" 
  name="root" 
  component={() => (<Redirect to="/public" />)} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

the statement is having `>>` at the end.

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/public" />>
```

can u try changing to

```
<Redirect from="/" to="/public" />
```

and then check?

Comment: Nope, i had fix that. And it is still rendering nothing